# Plotly Choropleth Map Error :ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.layout.Geo: 'sliders'

Tags: python, plotly

I have been learning to create a choropleth map with plotly that has a date slider, however, although I can get the map to output, I am receiving the following error when trying to add the slider. I've double checked the code, and compared it to the [tutorial](https://amaral.northwestern.edu/blog/step-step-how-plot-map-slider-represent-time-evolu) I've been following - however, I am using a different [data set](https://www.kaggle.com/pavan9065/air-pollution).

Error:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:15: SettingWithCopyWarning:


A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_43/4083138113.py in <module>
     44 
     45 fig = dict(data=data_slider, layout=layout)
---> 46 plotly.offline.iplot(fig)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/offline/offline.py in iplot(figure_or_data, show_link, link_text, validate, image, filename, image_width, image_height, config, auto_play, animation_opts)
    382 
    383     # Get figure
--> 384     figure = tools.return_figure_from_figure_or_data(figure_or_data, validate)
    385 
    386     # Handle image request

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/tools.py in return_figure_from_figure_or_data(figure_or_data, validate_figure)
    551 
    552         try:
--> 553             figure = Figure(**figure).to_dict()
    554         except exceptions.PlotlyError as err:
    555             raise exceptions.PlotlyError(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/_figure.py in __init__(self, data, layout, frames, skip_invalid, **kwargs)
    588             is invalid AND skip_invalid is False
    589         """
--> 590         super(Figure, self).__init__(data, layout, frames, skip_invalid, **kwargs)
    591 
    592     def add_bar(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in __init__(self, data, layout_plotly, frames, skip_invalid, **kwargs)
    558         # ### Import Layout ###
    559         self._layout_obj = self._layout_validator.validate_coerce(
--> 560             layout, skip_invalid=skip_invalid, _validate=self._validate
    561         )
    562 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_plotly_utils/basevalidators.py in validate_coerce(self, v, skip_invalid, _validate)
   2465 
   2466         elif isinstance(v, dict):
-> 2467             v = self.data_class(v, skip_invalid=skip_invalid, _validate=_validate)
   2468 
   2469         elif isinstance(v, self.data_class):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/_layout.py in __init__(self, arg, activeshape, annotations, annotationdefaults, autosize, autotypenumbers, bargap, bargroupgap, barmode, barnorm, boxgap, boxgroupgap, boxmode, calendar, clickmode, coloraxis, colorscale, colorway, computed, datarevision, dragmode, editrevision, extendfunnelareacolors, extendiciclecolors, extendpiecolors, extendsunburstcolors, extendtreemapcolors, font, funnelareacolorway, funnelgap, funnelgroupgap, funnelmode, geo, grid, height, hiddenlabels, hiddenlabelssrc, hidesources, hoverdistance, hoverlabel, hovermode, iciclecolorway, images, imagedefaults, legend, mapbox, margin, meta, metasrc, modebar, newshape, paper_bgcolor, piecolorway, plot_bgcolor, polar, scene, selectdirection, selectionrevision, separators, shapes, shapedefaults, showlegend, sliders, sliderdefaults, spikedistance, sunburstcolorway, template, ternary, title, titlefont, transition, treemapcolorway, uirevision, uniformtext, updatemenus, updatemenudefaults, violingap, violingroupgap, violinmode, waterfallgap, waterfallgroupgap, waterfallmode, width, xaxis, yaxis, **kwargs)
   6012         _v = geo if geo is not None else _v
   6013         if _v is not None:
-> 6014             self["geo"] = _v
   6015         _v = arg.pop("grid", None)
   6016         _v = grid if grid is not None else _v

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in __setitem__(self, prop, value)
   5819         if match is None:
   5820             # Set as ordinary property
-> 5821             super(BaseLayoutHierarchyType, self).__setitem__(prop, value)
   5822         else:
   5823             # Set as subplotid property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in __setitem__(self, prop, value)
   4809                 # ### Handle compound property ###
   4810                 if isinstance(validator, CompoundValidator):
-> 4811                     self._set_compound_prop(prop, value)
   4812 
   4813                 # ### Handle compound array property ###

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in _set_compound_prop(self, prop, val)
   5220         # ------------
   5221         validator = self._get_validator(prop)
-> 5222         val = validator.validate_coerce(val, skip_invalid=self._skip_invalid)
   5223 
   5224         # Save deep copies of current and new states

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_plotly_utils/basevalidators.py in validate_coerce(self, v, skip_invalid, _validate)
   2465 
   2466         elif isinstance(v, dict):
-> 2467             v = self.data_class(v, skip_invalid=skip_invalid, _validate=_validate)
   2468 
   2469         elif isinstance(v, self.data_class):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/layout/_geo.py in __init__(self, arg, bgcolor, center, coastlinecolor, coastlinewidth, countrycolor, countrywidth, domain, fitbounds, framecolor, framewidth, lakecolor, landcolor, lataxis, lonaxis, oceancolor, projection, resolution, rivercolor, riverwidth, scope, showcoastlines, showcountries, showframe, showlakes, showland, showocean, showrivers, showsubunits, subunitcolor, subunitwidth, uirevision, visible, **kwargs)
   1560         # Process unknown kwargs
   1561         # ----------------------
-> 1562         self._process_kwargs(**dict(arg, **kwargs))
   1563 
   1564         # Reset skip_invalid

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in _process_kwargs(self, **kwargs)
   4335                 self[k] = v
   4336             elif not self._skip_invalid:
-> 4337                 raise err
   4338         # No need to call _raise_on_invalid_property_error here,
   4339         # because we have it set up so that the singular case of calling

ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.layout.Geo: 'sliders'

Did you mean "center"?

Bad property path:
sliders
^^^^^^^
```

Code

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go 
import plotly.offline as offline


import time 
import plotly.express as px


fig = px.choropleth(df_total, locations="Code",
                    color="Total Deaths", # lifeExp is a column of gapminder
                    hover_name="Entity", # column to add to hover information
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=800,)



fig.show()
```

[image: Choropleth map]

```
#Slider

#color scale
scl = [[0.0, '#ffffff'],[0.2, '#ff9999'],[0.4, '#ff4d4d'], \
       [0.6, '#ff1a1a'],[0.8, '#cc0000'],[1.0, '#4d0000']] 

# min year in your dataset
year = 1990

data_slider = []
for year in df_total['Year'].unique():
    df_segmented =  df_total[(df_total['Year']== year)]

    for col in df_segmented.columns:
        df_segmented[col] = df_segmented[col].astype(str)

    data_each_yr = dict(
                        type='choropleth',
                        locations = df_segmented['Entity'],
                        z=df_segmented['Total Deaths'].astype(float),
                        locationmode= 'country names',
                        colorscale = scl,
                        colorbar= {'title':'# Deaths - Total Air pollution Deaths'})

    data_slider.append(data_each_yr)

steps = []
for i in range(len(data_slider)):
    step = dict(method='restyle',
                args=['visible', [False] * len(data_slider)],
                label='Year {}'.format(i + 1990))
    step['args'][1][i] = True
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(active=0, pad={"t": 1}, steps=steps)]


layout = dict(title ='Global Air Pollution Deaths 1990-2020', geo=dict(
        showframe=False,
        showcoastlines=False,
        projection_type='equirectangular',
              sliders=sliders))

              
fig = dict(data=data_slider, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the writing of the conditionally extracted data frame, so put the extraction result in a temporary data frame and add it to the data frame in its final form.

```
df_sected_crime = pd.DataFrame()
for year in df_merged.Year.unique():
    # I select the year (and remove DC for now)
    tmp = df_merged[(df_merged['State'] != 'District of Columbia' ) &  (df_merged['Year']== year )]
    tmp2 = tmp.copy()
    #for col in df_sected_crime.columns:  # I transform the columns into string type so I can:
        #df_sected_crime[col] = df_sected_crime[col].astype(str)

    ### I create the text for mouse-hover for each state, for the current year    
    tmp2['text'] = tmp2['State'] + '</br>Pop: ' + tmp2['Population'].astype(str) + '</br>Murder rate: '+ tmp2['Murder_per100000'].astype(str)
    df_sected_crime = df_sected_crime.append(tmp2)

    ### create the dictionary with the data for the current year
    data_one_year = dict(
                        type='choropleth',
                        locations = df_sected_crime['State_code'],
                        z=df_sected_crime['Murder_per100000'].astype(float),
                        locationmode='USA-states',
                        colorscale = scl,
                        text = df_sected_crime['text'],
                        )

    data_slider.append(data_one_year)  # I add the dictionary to the list of dictionaries for the slider
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anything unsatisfactory about my answer? If so, could you please comment on it?